# Hi! Im trying to pass selectedArray from SelectTheMode to Game component, but for some reason it doesn't work well

Tags: reactjs

Here is the code, i need the selected array to pass to game component, but for some reason it does not work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const SelectTheMode = () => {
  const [selectedArray, setSelectedArray] = useState('');
  const [tabIndexSelected, setTabIndexSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleDivClick = (arrayName) => {
    setSelectedArray(arrayName);
    setTabIndexSelected(true);
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log(selectedArray);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>Выбери режим игры</h1>
      </header>
      <div onClick={() => handleDivClick("Array1")} tabIndex="1" className='ModeContainer'>
        <h1></h1>
        <h2>Базовый</h2>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h4>
      </div>
            {/* some containers */}

      {tabIndexSelected ? (
        <div>
          <Link className='NextButton' onClick={handleButtonClick} to='/teams'>Далее</Link>
        </div>
      ) : null}

    </div>
  );
};

export default SelectTheMode;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const Game = ({ selectedArray }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {selectedArray}
     selectedArray={selectedArray}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import AddTeams from './Pages/AddTeams';
import SelectTheMode from './Pages/SelectTheMode';
import Game from './Pages/Game';

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <SelectTheMode/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/teams" component={AddTeams}/>
        <Route path="/game">
          <Game/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to put this in the SelectTheMode but it returned the selectedArray in the SelectTheMode component, not in the Game component. I really don't know how to solve this kind of problem, literally begging for help

```
{tabIndexSelected ? (
        <div>
          <Link className='NextButton' onClick={handleButtonClick} to='/teams'>Далее</Link>
        </div>
      ) : null}

      {tabIndexSelected && <Game selectedArray={selectedArray} />}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it seems like the value you are passing to the **handleDivClick** handler is a **string ("Array1")**. Also, at the time of setting the initial state, no array is passed to the hook (useState(' ')). Following are the snapshots of the code I'm talking about:

1.

```
      <div onClick={() => handleDivClick("Array1")} tabIndex="1" className='ModeContainer'>
        <h1></h1>
        <h2>Базовый</h2>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h4>
      </div>
```

2. const [selectedArray, setSelectedArray] = useState('');

I could be wrong or maybe you've omitted some code in your post here. If there is any other information you can provide, it would be of help in understanding the problem better. Also, I see that **handleButtonClick** is supposed to log the array. Is it working? If yes, what is the output?

Comment: yes, i had more containers with different values on handleDivClick("Array1")}
i wanted to pass the value that was selected to the Game component